# How do I Compile and Deploy an assembly into a custom path using visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, assemblies

I've been searching this for a long while and i could find anything. I have 2 projects. One called ConsoleApp and other called ConsoleLib. ConsoleApp has a reference to ConsoleLib.
How can i Tell visual studio to copy the assembly into a custom path instead of the app path?
What i want to mean is that when i build the solution i want to get this folder structure

AppPath\ConsoleApp.exe

AppPath\Lib\

AppPath\Lib\ConsoleLib.dll

Comment: First, thank you for the answers. Second s_ruchit I've already figured out that posibility. I've read in Effective C# (Bill Wagner Book) that you can set a private bin path for an assembly. In order for the loader to search that path too. The reason behind wanting to move the lib assembly into another directory is to keep the binaries better structured. Mi question is how can i set the private bin path of an assembly or have i missunderstanded the concept? Thank you for answering again

Comment: The private bin path that you are looking for is the probing element that I have linked to in my answer

Answer (score 2):

- In your ConsoleApp project refer the ConsolLib project which will receive the ConsolLib.dll in ConsolApp\Bin.
- Now in the ConsoleApp project goto **PostBuild commands** there you can sepcify the operations you may wnat to execute after the build and there you can have it copied to ConsoleApp\Lib.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a postbuild command in the application project to create the lib directory and copy the library file into it.

If you decide to do this (which I wouldn't recommend unless you have lots of dlls and feel an overwhelming urge to organise them) you also need to add a probing path element to your app.config file that will tell it where to look for the libraries. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use a postbuild command (I'm using subdir "release" in output)

```
mkdir "$(TargetDir)release\"
mkdir "$(TargetDir)release\bin\"

copy "$(TargetDir)*.*" "$(TargetDir)release\"
copy "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(TargetDir)release\bin\"
copy "$(TargetDir)*.pdb" "$(TargetDir)release\bin\"  

del "$(TargetDir)release\*.pdb"
del "$(TargetDir)release\*.dll"
del "$(TargetDir)release\*vshost*.*"
```

In app.config then :

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="bin"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Hope this helps